# Array of pointers to char * in c using qsort

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

While adding string to my pointer's array, it is being overwriten by the last one. Could anyone tell me, where's my mistake?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
int ile = 3;
const char * slowa[ile];
for(int j = 0; j < ile; j++){
    char string[30];
    gets(string); 
    slowa[j] = string;
    printf ("%s dodalem pierwsza\n",string);
}
for (int i = 0; i < ile; i++) {
    printf ("%s numer %d\n",slowa[i],i);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no qsort in your code snippet and your problem has nothing to do with sorting. Can you fix the title of your question?

Comment: Not the issue, but: **never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the C standard 5 years ago and has been deprecated since 1999. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Yeah that's true @Olaf, I'm pretty sure the newest version of `gcc` warns you not to use it.

Comment: @RoadRunner: As gcc (and clang) does not implement the standard libary, but is - strictly speaking - a freestanding implementation, it can hardly warn. And as it is not part of the standard, your library should not declare it at all, so you get a normal "function without declaration" (or similar) warning and a linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the following two lines of code:

```
char string[30];
...
slowa[j] = string;
```

The assignment sets `slowa[j]` to the address of the *same* buffer, without making a copy. Hence, the last thing that you put in the buffer would be referenced by all elements of `slowa[]` array, up to position of `j-1`.

In order to fix this problem, make copies before storing values in `slowa`. You can use non-standard `strdup`, or use `malloc`+`strcpy`:

```
char string[30];
gets(string);
slowa[j] = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
strcpy(slowa[j], string);
```

In both cases you need to call `free` on all elements of `slowa[]` array to which you have assigned values in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: It is actually worse: The buffer does not exist after the first loop, so the program invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You're always pointing to array of chars which is stack variable it's locally allocated only in scope of function, possibly each declaration of string will be on the same address as previous iteration in your loop. You could either instead of using array of chars allocate memory each loop iteration or use array and then using i.e strdup allocate memory for your new string like

```
slowa[j] = strdup(string) :
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to create copies of the strings, otherwise you set the strings to the same address, and therefore they just overwrite each other.

Additionally, I think using [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) over [`gets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm) is a much safer approach. This is because `gets` is very prone to [buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), whereas with `fgets`, you can easily check for buffer overflow.

This is some code I wrote a while ago which is similar to what you are trying to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PTRS 3
#define STRLEN 30

int
string_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char *str1 = *(const char**)a;
    const char *str2 = *(const char**)b;
    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

int 
main(void) {
    char *strings[PTRS];
    char string[STRLEN];
    int str;
    size_t len, i = 0;

    while (i < PTRS) {

        printf("Enter a string: ");
        if (fgets(string, STRLEN, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading string");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        len = strlen(string);

        if (string[len-1] == '\n') {
            string[len-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            break;
        }

        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
        if (strings[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Cannot malloc string");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcpy(strings[i], string);

        i++;
    }

    qsort(strings, i, sizeof(*strings), string_cmp);

    printf("\nSuccessfully read strings(in sorted order):\n");
    for (str = 0; str < i; str++) {
        printf("strings[%d] = %s\n", str, strings[str]);
        free(strings[str]);
        strings[str] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```